# php include: ms word generated html file and garbage css

Tags: php, ms-word

word generated html sucks, of course. but i unfortunately need to fetch some text from such existing docs to my php pages. the problem is, then it messes up my original page's css. what could be a way out? thanks!

Comment: Can you post some sample code of your msword html file along with your php code and your messed up css?

Comment: better not, alec - it may f*** SO up :)

Answer (score 4):

Try [this](http://snipplr.com/view/5217/clean-word-html-using-regular-expressions/) out. It's a ereg function that clears some of the Word HTML out of a string.

Comment: +1 however but a little bit more detail in your answer as to what the link points to.

Answer (score 0):

or [html tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html#word-2000) and [here](http://www.php.net/tidy)